# "Column Not Found" error?

Tags: java, database

I need help with the below error. Below is the method, retrievePassword(). I programmed it so that when the Clickid is called, I can retrieve all other datas too.

```
public boolean retrievePassword() {
  // declare local variables
  boolean success = false;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  DBController db = new DBController();

  // step 1 of using DBController, passing data source name setup during last practical
  db.setUp("myDatabase");

  // declare the SQL 
  String dbQuery = "SELECT Clickid FROM PROFILE WHERE Clickid = '" + clickId + "'" ;


  // step 2 of using DBCcontroller, for retrieve SQL use readRequest method
  rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
  try{
     if (rs.next()){
   firstName = rs.getString("Firstname");
   lastName = rs.getString("LastName");
          password = rs.getString("Password");
          email = rs.getString("Email");

          success = true;     
     }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  db.terminate();
  return success;
 }
```

I have checked and all the column names are correct. I think the problem lies with either the above method or the instantiation below

```
 String first = jTextFieldFirst.getText();
 String email = jTextFieldEmail.getText();
 Profile p2 = new Profile(jTextFieldId.getText());
 p2.retrievePassword();
 String firstName = p2.getFirstName();
 String email2 = p2.getEmail();
 if(email == email2 && first == firstName)
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Password is "+p2.getPassword(),
        "Retrieve Password",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
else
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some information you entered is incorrect", "Retrieve Password",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

When I compiled and typed in the respective fields, the error "Column not found" keeps appearing. I have ensured that the column names and data are correct but I have more columns that I didnt include in the retrievePassword() method. I am sure it is either of this 2 methods that seems to be the problem but I cant seems to solve it no matter how I do it. Will some kind soul help me? Please?

Comment: You probably shouldn't even have a function called "retrieve password" since the database should never have stored the password in the first place.  It should be storing an irreversible hash of the password.

Comment: Regarding that part, I am still not really good with the things other than database. So I used the most primitive method this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you select only the clickid column.
try 
select * from profile
or better use a column list.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your query only selects the ClickId field but then in your result you're trying to obtain other fields. Use SELECT * or SELECT with the fields you need instead.

Comment: Please, no `select *`. This is very error prone if one day somebody decides to change a bit the table's structure. All hell will break loose. Select only what you need. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Yeah you're right it's better to just select what you need, I mentioned it in case he didn't know how to select all.

Comment: @darioo: I'm not sure how "all hell would break loose" unless you changed column names, in which case an explicit select clause would also fail.  Are you thinking that it's better that the execute fail rather than later on when dealing with the result set?  Or are you mistakenly thinking the OP/anybody is interacting with the RS using the column index?

Comment: @Mark: we had a situation where `select *` was used in many places. Also, when iterating on RS, column index was used. Then it was decided that one DB table needed "restructuring". Short story: some columns were added, some were swapped. All selects started to fail, obviously, and had to be rewritten.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek What is mean :-> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '''' in 'where clause' and my where clause is :->  WHERE (`''` = '''') full code : https://justpaste.it/5vz3d

Comment: @Gem I think you should ask this in your own question, but what exactly are you expecting here? What are you comparing with what?

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek someone already post in Magento Forum, can you pls see that : https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/Magento-SOAP-V2-Unknown-column-Error/m-p/113643/highlight/true#M9318

Comment: @Gem you’re not even filling in a column name,  please make a post here of your own code with your own details.

Comment: @seba I am using soap API, how can I change?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, you need to retrieve FirstName, LastName, Email, and Password in your select query if you're going to be using them from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Hey all, I did what you all said and selected all the columns and it was a success. But when I implement the method below

```
 String first = jTextFieldFirst.getText();
 String email = jTextFieldEmail.getText();
 Profile p2 = new Profile(jTextFieldId.getText());
 p2.retrievePassword();
 String firstName = p2.getFirstName();
 String email2 = p2.getEmail();

if(email == email2 && first == firstName)
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Password is "+p2.getPassword(),
        "Retrieve Password",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
else
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some information you entered is incorrect", "Retrieve Password",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

It keeps showing the jOptionPane from the else loop. What i need is actually to get the if loop out when I typed in the correct field =(. Thanks for all of your help =)